# The existence of a continuous map based on any Lipschitz map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

The question is the following:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces. A map $f:X \to Y$ is called *Lipschitz continuous* if there exists $C \geq 0$ such that 
>   $$
> d_Y(f(x),f(y)) \leq Cd_X(x,y),\ \forall x,y \in X
> $$
>   The smallest possible constant for the above inequality is called the *Lipschitz constant* $Lip(f)$ of $f$.
>
> Let $\tilde{X}$ be a metric space and $X$ be a dense subset of $\tilde{X}$. Let $Y$ be a complete metric space. Then,
>
> (a) For any Lipschitz map $f:X \to Y$, prove that there exists a unique continuous map $\tilde{f}: \tilde{X} \to Y$ such that $\tilde{f}|_X = f$. Moreover $\tilde{f} $ is Lipschitz and $Lip(\tilde{f}) = Lip(f)$.
>
> (b) Show that one cannot replace "Lipschitz" in (a) by "continuous".

I come up with the following construction (could be wrong):
$$
\begin{cases}
    f(x) \quad &\text{if }x \in X \\
    \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) \quad &\text{if } x \in \tilde{X} \setminus X,\ a_n \in X,\ a_n \to x
\end{cases}
$$
based on the definidion of $X$. But I am not sure that what I need to prove to make this function well-defined. I may know how to approach the continuity, but I have no idea to prove the uniqueness. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, in a good stated math problem I would argue that all assumptions are either necessary or can be at least used to make things technically easier. So can you for example see where you might need to argue with completeness of $Y$? Would your construction be well-defined if $Y$ would not be complete? What do you know about limits and uniqueness in metric spaces? (Not saying all of these question are relevant, but I think they are worth thinking about.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define directly that $\widetilde{f}(x)=lim f(a_{n})$ for $a_{n}\in X$ that $a_{n}\rightarrow x$.

For $(a_{n}),(b_{n})$ both $a_{n}\rightarrow x$ and $b_{n}\rightarrow x$, consider $c_{2n+1}=a_{n}$ and $c_{2n}=b_{n}$, then $c_{n}\rightarrow x$ and $d(f(c_{n}),f(c_{m}))\leq Cd(c_{n},c_{m})\rightarrow 0$. As $Y$ is complete, $f(c_{n})\rightarrow y$. But $(f(a_{n}))$ and $(f(b_{n}))$ are subsequences of $(f(c_{n}))$, so $y=\lim f(a_{n})=\lim f(b_{n})$ and hence it is well-defined.

Consider the constant sequence $(x,x,...)$, $x\in X$, then $\widetilde{f}(x)=f(x)$.

To prove the continuity, note that $d(\widetilde{f}(x),\widetilde{f}(y))=\lim d(f(a_{n}),f(b_{n}))\leq\lim d(a_{n},b_{n})=d(x,y)$ for $a_{n}\rightarrow x, b_{n}\rightarrow y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have question here: since it states $\tilde{f}|_X = f$, does it mean that for all $x \in X$, we should have $\tilde{f} = f$? But in your answer, it is only true for the constant sequence.

Comment: I really proved that $\widetilde{f}(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in X$. The reasoning is that, I defined the value of $\widetilde{f}$ through the limit process, the constant sequence $(x,x,...)$ has limit exactly $x$ and this gives the value of $\widetilde{f}$ at $x$ is exactly $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Let me go through the whole process again.